# estoy creando un pequeño formulario con imagen

Tags: reactjs

Al momento de subir la la imagen lo envía automáticamente estoy usando axios ya lo convertí en base64 he creado dos funciones para cada imagen también es posible enviarlo con una sola función ?
Gracias

https://github.com/TecWilfridoGarcia/register-team-react.js

```
onChangeFlag(e){
let files = e.target.files;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
reader.onload = (e) => {
  const url="http://localhost:3000/array-team";
  var formDataImagesFlag = {flag:e.target.result};  
  console.log(formDataImagesFlag);
 }
}

 handleSubmit = e => {
 const teamItem = {
  team: this.state.team,
  flag: this.formDataImagesFlag,
  shield: this.formDataImagesShield
  }
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/array-team', teamItem
   ).then(
    res => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);

    }
   )
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. La verdad es que no sé si lo que escribes es una pregunta o una afirmación. ¿Cuál es la duda? Porque en la pregunta no planteas ninguna duda. Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo edite es un pregunta

Comment: El problema es que no estás explicando cual es tu problema. Con agregar un signo de interrogación no lo hace una pregunta, lo que importa es que la frase tenga intención de pregunta. Quizás mejorando la redacción para que suene como pregunta o agregando más información, pero de verdad que no queda claro lo que estás preguntando. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres es reutilizar la función que controla los file inputs.

Puedes obtener el nombre del input desde el objeto del evento y guardarlo en el estado hasta finalmente enviar el formulario

```
  onFileChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]) // o lo que sea que uses
    })
  }
```

render:

```
 <div className="form-group">
     <label>Bandera:</label>
     <input type="file" className="form-control-file" name="flag" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
 </div>
 <div className="form-group">
     <label>Escudo:</label>
     <input type="file" className="form-control-file" name="shield" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
  </div>
```

Y finalmente:

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!validate(this.state)) {
    alert('Campo vacio!');
    return;
  }

  const data = { 
   team: this.state.team, 
   shield: this.state.shield, 
   flag: this.state.flag 
  }; 

  this.setState({ loading: true })

  axios.post('miservicio.com/api/team/', data)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('success', res);
    setState({ loading: false })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.err(err)
    setState({ loading: false })
    alert(err.message);
  })
}
```

De hecho podrías usar una sola función para todos los inputs, no solo los de archivos:

```
onChange(e) {
  const { type, name, files } = e.target;
  let value = e.target.value; // por defecto, para los input de tipo text

  if(type === 'file') {
     if(!files || !files[0]) return;
     value = ... // imagen en base64
  }

  this.setState({ [name] : value });
}
```